How to create a pull request using the Azure DevOps plugin in JetBrains Rider?
I have installed the Azure DevOps plugin for Rider on macOS, and I am trying to create a pull request from my local branch into the remote master branch up on DevOps. I was able to authenticate and clone the repo from the Open from Version Control dialog, and I can push to the upstream branch directly, but I can't find anything about creating a pull request.
I've looked in View -> Tool Windows as well as the whole Git menu, including the Push dialog, but nothing. The plugin is enabled and properly authenticated. Any insight as to what's going on?

Also asked on StackOverflow
